# Generate web page from Database using AllowHtml in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an application use Asp.Net 4.61 in which I read html from a database field Description and use it to populate my a page in my application.  I do this by marking the property Description with `[AllowHtml]`.

In my Asp.Net Core 2.0 app, I get an error that the assembly reference or directive is not found.

I have 2 questions - that will hopefully enable me to better answer questions such as this in the future:

1. Is there a document/site that I could search to see if AllowHtml is
   in Core 2.0
2. Is there a better/more secure way that I should use if I want to
   populate web pages by reading from my database than decorating the field/property with `[AllowHtml]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need [AllowHtml] anymore, because nobody denies HTML in ASP.NET Core 2.0:

> [Don't need [AllowHtml] or RequestValidationEnabled because we don't have request validation in this system](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/324#issuecomment-50082022)

Instead, [encode the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#validation) and [Prevent Cross-Site Scripting](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cross-site-scripting.html)

Comment: Home come this is not needed anymore yet HTML data is sanitized in POST request. In other words there's data loss in POST parameter when it has HTML/CSS markup.

I'm still trying to figure this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483284/passing-raw-html-from-view-to-controller-xss-safe-no-information-loss).