# What is the alternate of [AllowHtml] in ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to integrate CKEditor in my MVC Core 2.0 Application, in previous version I used it by adding [AllowHTML] data annotation to my string property. But in ASP.Net Core I could not find the right way to insert HTML into string input.

My code in in ASP.Net MVC 5

```
[AllowHtml]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Profile { get; set; }
```

but in ASP.Net Core 2.0 [AllowHtml] is not working. I searched in google but could not find right solution except this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Profile { get; set; }
```

I am really stuck with this issue and need help from .Net experts, Thanks.

Comment: It no longer exists - refer [Generate web page from Database using AllowHtml in Asp.Net Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230623/generate-web-page-from-database-using-allowhtml-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

Comment: Actually I want to integrate CKEDITOR in my application. and @Html.TextAreaFor(item => item.Profile, new { @id = "editor1" }) render CKEDITOR correctly but when I use HTML Tag Helpers <textarea asp-for="Profile" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea> it does not render CKEDITOR

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Comment: CKEDITOR not working  when I use public string Profile { get; set; }

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/

Comment: Thanks Stephen, CKEDITOR started working now. It was a CSS id issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using Asp.Net Core razor you can output raw html into the page via the following:

```
     @Html.Raw(theString)
```

I feel obligated to point out that you need to ensure that `theString` contains safe HTML to output such that it isn't an open door for XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that and its working fine. That topic already resolved.